# Java - Decimal to Binary (and vice versa) using bitwise operators

Tags: java, binary, decimal

I'm new to Stack Exchange, by the way - thought I'd point that out. I'm having trouble with a program that is supposed to convert a decimal number to it's binary form using bitwise operators (no modulo or division!!), and signs don't matter in this case. The thing is, I don't even know if what I have so far (see below) it's first or not - I can't even read the output! I'm using IntelliJ 2017.3, and I know that's not the case for the word format. If anyone needs more information, I'll provide it.

Code (UPDATED):

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.PrintStream;

public class Main
{
    public static char[] DecToBinary(int number)
    {
        // The output array that the binary version of "number" is stored in
        char output[] = new char[32];
        // The mask used to check if the bytes are all set
        int mask = 1;
        // The binary array used to store the binary number
        char[] binaryString = new char[output.length];
        char[] binary = Integer.toBinaryString(number).toCharArray();
        // Storing the binary value in the binary string array
        for (int i = binary.length - 1; i > 0; i--)
        {
            binaryString[i] = binary[i];
        }
        // Looping through the BS array, starting from the end of the array
        // (so that the output looks something like this: 01111000 - that's 120 in Binary)
        for (int i = 31; i > 0; i--)
        {
            // Checking if the bytes are all set using the AND operator
            output[i] = binaryString[i];
            if ((number & mask) == 0)
            {
                output[i] = '0';
            } else if ((number & mask) != 0)
            {
                output[i] = '1';
            }
            mask >>>= 1;
        }
        // Storing the binary string in the output array
        for (int i = 32; i > output.length; i--)
        {
            output[i] = binaryString[i];
        }
        mask = mask << 1;
        // Return the output array
        return output;
    }

    // To be developed...eventually.
    public static int BinaryToDec(char number[])
    {
        int output = 0;
        return output;
    }

    public static void println(String prefix, char array[])
    {
        System.out.print(prefix);
        for (char c : array)
        {
            System.out.print(c);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    public static void print(String prefix, char array[])
    {
        System.out.print(prefix);
        for (char c : array)
        {
            System.out.print(c);
        }
    }

    public static void TestDecToBinary()
    {
        int valuesToTest[] = { 0, 1, -1, 100, -100, 2147483647, -2147483648 };

        System.out.println("    Decimal     Binary");
        for (int index = 0; index < valuesToTest.length; ++index)
        {
            System.out.format("%11d     ", valuesToTest[index]);
            println("", DecToBinary(valuesToTest[index]));
        }
    }

    public static void TestBinToDecimal()
    {
        char valuesToTest[][] = { { '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0' }, { '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1' }, { '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1' }, { '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '1', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0' }, { '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '0', '0', '1', '1', '1', '0', '0' },
                { '0', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1' }, { '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0' } };

        System.out.println("Binary                                Decimal");
        for (int index = 0; index < valuesToTest.length; ++index)
        {
            print("", valuesToTest[index]);
            System.out.format("  %11d\n", BinaryToDec(valuesToTest[index]));
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        /*File file = new File("myOutput.txt");
        FileOutputStream fos;
        try
        {
            fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
            PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(fos);
            System.setOut(ps);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }*/
        TestDecToBinary();
        System.out.format("\n\n");
        TestBinToDecimal();
    }
}
```

Output for Decimal-Binary Conversion (I have to take a screenshot of this, because when I copy it all it pastes is just spaces):

[image: New output for Decimal-Binary Conversion]

Comment: Try `output[i] = '0'`, similarly for '1'.

Comment: The thing is, I'm supposed to use bitwise operators. I can't use anything else, so... Yeah. Any suggestions?

Comment: Still no changes, unfortunately... The output's still a bunch of X boxes...

Comment: Where are you returning `output`? And how are you printing? Show your whole code. And why can't you just print String `binary`. Isn't that your answer?

Comment: Either do it using the `Integer.toBinaryString` method or do it using bitwise operations like you stated you wanted to do. You are trying to use two different methods at the same time and you are confusing yourself.

Comment: What is the value of `output.length` in this loop? How many times does this loop run. Use a debugger and/or add print statements to debug your code. `for (int i = 32; i > output.length; i--)`

Comment: Output.length is the value of the char array's length, 32. The loop ends when "I" reaches 0, the beginning of the output array.

Comment: No, the loop ends when the statement `i > output.length` is false. And because `output.length` is 32, this statement is false the first time it is evaluated (when `i=32`)

Comment: There is no decimal to binary conversion here. There is (1) binary to binary String and then (2) binary string back to binary. Unclear what you're asking.

Comment: @EJP are you seriously unclear what the op is asking??

Comment: @MFisherKDX I am seriously *clear* that there is no decimal to binary conversion here, unless you count what the *compiler* does with the integer constants in the array initializer, which I don't. And as that is the title of his question, and reiterated inside it, it is therefore totally unclear what he is talking about.

Comment: This is what I'm asking, just to be clear (Idk if you all didn't get this from my original post): I'm trying to convert a decimal number to  it's binary value using bitwise operators (shifting, AND/OR, etc.) and no modulo or division. And MFisherKDX - I tried what you said, and fixed the loop. It helped a little, but I'm still not getting the output I need. Also, this thread is getting a little too long... Should we move to chat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your loops are not executing. You should use a debugger or add print statements to debug your code. For instance, you create arrays `output` and `binaryString` of size 32 elements and then loop as so: `for (int i = 32; i > binaryString.length ; i--)`. Your loop body will never execute and your array `output` will not be populated. When you return it, it still has default values of 0, which are not printable in your console.

Secondly, using `Integer.toBinaryString` is probably cheating. If it we're allowed you return a one liner: `Integer.toBinaryString(num).toCharArray()` and be done with it.

Comment: While it would be cheating to use it, it would be good idea to use it for testing, whether the code works.